# Move current line up/down but keep cursor position

Tags: vimrc

I'm using:

```
" move current line up
imap [u <esc>:m .-2<CR>i
" move current line down
imap [d <esc>:m+<CR>i
```

But I'd like to keep the current cursor position, and I would like to expand the question to move up/down a block of text.

EDIT 1: for example:
`The current line ->| need to move up is here`

`->|` is the cursor's position that we need to keep moving.

Comment: These are insert-mode mappings.  How could you move up/down a block of text in insert mode since you cannot select text in insert mode?

Comment: It doesn't matter in v, n, i mode. Just describe what I'm using right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ddp` and `ddkP` put the cursor at the begin of the line.

The solution was found on [http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down#Mappings_to_move_lines)

For insert mode:

```
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>:m .+1<CR>==gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>:m .-2<CR>==gi
```

For blocks of code:

```
vnoremap <A-j> :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap <A-k> :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

After selection of a block, press `<A-j>` to move the whole block down, `<A-k>` to move it up.

For normal mode:

```
nnoremap <A-j> :m .+1<CR>==
nnoremap <A-k> :m .-2<CR>==
```

Comment: We always have cursor but its position reset to beginning of that line. Kind of obviously.

Comment: I try `imap <c-u> <esc>:mk<CR>:m .-2<CR>\`ki` but get error `E189: "_exrc" exists (add ! to override)`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @ommision: How can I keep cursor's position in normal mode?

Comment: @TuyenPham In normal mode easiest way is to use a mark: `nnoremap [u mz:m .-2<cr>\`z` and `nnoremap [d mz:m .+1<cr>\`z`

Comment: @Rich: It works, but up is pretty slow, doesn't work with block. Tope brings faster up with tpope/vim-unimpaired - doesn't work with block either.

Comment: @TuyenPham You might have better luck if you describe more precisely what you want to achieve. "Work with block" isn't the most exhaustive of specifications!

Comment: My mistake, misread your comment, thought it's visual mode.

Answer (score 2):

I interpreted "keep position" as the cursor does not move, at all, which may not be what the question intended.  **Note**: this only works with `set nostartofline`.

*Partial answer for the insert-mode case*: There are two cases to consider.  The trick is to remember `:move` puts the cursor at the new position.

**Current line up**: instead of moving the current line up, we move the previous line to just below the cursor line.

`inoremap [u <c-o>:-1m.<cr>`

**Current line down**: instead of moving the current line down, we move the next line to just before the cursor line.

`inoremap [d <c-o>:+1m-1<cr>`

Note: in either case, we use `inoremap` and `<c-o>`, which are preferable to `imap` and `<esc>`...`i`.

Comment: Weird, just seen your answer that posted 2 hours later but important matter keeping position is not answered yet. inoremap is good to use.

Comment: This answer actually does keep position, do you not observe this?

Comment: Same result as my code.

Comment: @Mass When I test your solution in `vim -Nu NONE` (Vim 7.4) the cursor stays on the same line *number*, but moves to the start of the line. i.e. it doesn't move vertically, but it *does* move horizontally. Could the behaviour be inconsistent across versions?

Comment: @Rich, yes, my mistake.  I think it works with `set nostartofline` but not by default.